# Firestore Rules nested 'get' functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have started a Cloud Firestore Database and i set two collections:

**Users**
That have document data object
`{ userRole: string, userPermissions: Array<string> }`

**Roles**
That have document data object
`{ rolePermissions: Array<string> }`

I've added as rules the following:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userID} {
        //User Profiles
      allow read: if isUserValid();
      allow write: if isUserValid();
    }
    
    match /roles/{roleID} {
        //User Roles
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if isUserValid() && (hasUserPermission('ADMIN.ROLES') || hasRolePermission('ADMIN.ROLES'));
    }

    function isExist() {
      return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid));
    }
  
    function isUserValid() {
      return isExist() &&
      (get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.userActive  == true);
    }
    
    function hasUserPermission(permission) {
      let queryPermissions = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.userPermissions;
      return permission in queryPermissions;
    }
    
    function hasRolePermission(permission) {
      let queryRole = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.userRole;
      let queryPermissions = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/roles/$(queryRole)).data.rolePermissions;
      return permission in queryPermissions;
    }
  }
}
```

When i Test the rule what happen is:

- the function "hasUserPermission(permission)" it's working properly
- the function "hasRolePermission(permission)" return an error:
  `Error: simulator.rules line [38], column [30]. Function not found error: Name: [get].; Error: Invalid argument provided to call. Function: [get], Argument: ["||invalid_argument||"]`

Why doesn't work?